# Add dash to each child of multi level category in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, ecmascript-6, ecmascript-5

I have a multi level array of categories like this:

```
[
        {
            "id": 5,
            "parent_id": 3,
            "name": "Fruits",
            "parent": {
                "id": 3,
                "parent_id": 1,
                "name": "Vegetables and fruits",
            }
        },
        {
            "id": 6,
            "parent_id": 3,
            "name": "Vegetables",
            "parent": {
                "id": 3,
                "parent_id": 1,
                "name": "Vegetables and fruits",
            }
        },
        {
            "id": 3,
            "parent_id": null,
            "name": "Vegetables and fruits",
            "parent": null
        },
]
```

I want to add '-' (dash) prefix to each child of categories according to level. For example, first level has one dash '-', third level has two dash '--'.

How can I update array like this?

I tried some code.

```
const updateData = (data) => {
    return data.map(item => {
        if (item.parent_id != null) {
            // Maybe there use recursive
            item.name = `-${item.name }`;
        }
        return item;
    })
}
```

Excepted output:

```
Vegetables and fruits
Drinks
-Fruits
-Vegetables
--Tomatos
--Potatos
```

Comment: Find the root node first, then it's children, etc and keep track of the current level.

Comment: what is expected output?

Comment: @RahulKumar I add expected output to question

Comment: in input example tomatoes, potatoes and drinks are not mentioned. please complete your input. Is there only 2 levels or more?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can create a `getLevel` function to determine the level of any node, then use this to decide the number of dashes to use:

```js
let input = [ { "id": 5, "parent_id": 3, "name": "Fruits", "parent": { "id": 3, "parent_id": 1, "name": "Vegetables and fruits", } }, { "id": 6, "parent_id": 3, "name": "Vegetables", "parent": { "id": 3, "parent_id": 1, "name": "Vegetables and fruits", } }, { "id": 3, "parent_id": null, "name": "Vegetables and fruits", "parent": null }, { "id": 7, "parent_id": 5, "name": "Strawberries", "parent": { "id": 5, "parent_id": 3, "name": "Vegetables and fruits", } }, { "id": 8, "parent_id": 6, "name": "Tomatos", "parent": { "id": 6, "parent_id": 3, "name": "Vegetables and fruits", } }, ]

// Pre-compute object / parent mapping
const parentMap = input.reduce((acc,obj) => { 
    acc[obj.id] = obj?.parent;
    return acc;
}, {})

// Find the node level based on its parent id.
function getLevel(parentMap, obj) {
     let level = 0;
     while (parentMap[obj.id]) {
         level++;
         obj = parentMap[obj.id] 
     }
     return level;
}

const result = input.map(obj => {
    level = getLevel(parentMap , obj);
    return { ...obj, level} ;
})
.sort((a,b) => a.level - b.level)
.map(obj => '-'.repeat(obj.level) + obj.name)

console.log('Result:', result)
```

Comment: This will cause *a lot* of traversal for longer lists and/or deeper hierarchies. It's better to pre-compute the tree relationship once which can be done in `O(n)` and then use that to find the depth of each node.

Comment: Yes indeed, I appreciate that VLAZ, you're absolutely right. For smaller lists it would be fine, but I'll update to make it O(n)...

Answer (score 1):

One way to do it would be to transform your input in a list of trees (since you can have separate roots). Then it becomes really easy to go through them and print them recursively. Here is the implementation I would use:

```js
const input = [
        {
            "id": 5,
            "parent_id": 3,
            "name": "Fruits",
            "parent": {
                "id": 3,
                "parent_id": 1,
                "name": "Vegetables and fruits",
            }
        },
        {
            "id": 6,
            "parent_id": 3,
            "name": "Vegetables",
            "parent": {
                "id": 3,
                "parent_id": 1,
                "name": "Vegetables and fruits",
            }
        },
        {
            "id": 3,
            "parent_id": null,
            "name": "Vegetables and fruits",
            "parent": null
        },
]


function buildTrees(input) {
  const mapping = new Map()

    // Creating a mapping based on the item id
  input.forEach(i => {
    delete i.parent // parent detail is not needed
    i.children = []
    mapping.set(i.id, i)
  })

    // Adding every node to its parent children list
  input.filter(i => i.parent_id !== null).forEach(i => {
    mapping.get(i.parent_id).children.push(i)
  })

    // Returning the roots
  return input.filter(i => i.parent_id === null).map(i => mapping.get(i.id))
}

function printTree(tree, depth) {
    // Recursively prints the names
    console.log('-'.repeat(depth) + ' ' + tree.name)
  tree.children.forEach(child => printTree(child, depth + 1))
}

const trees = buildTrees(input)

trees.forEach(tree => printTree(tree, 0))
```